# Using converter for custom objects in selectCheckboxMenu doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use an converter for custom objects, that are used in a primefaces' `selectCheckboxMenu`.

This is the JSF part:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg.cars}: " for="cars" />
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="cars"
    value="#{controller.selected.cars}"
    converter="carConverter" label="#{msg.cars}"
    filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
    panelStyle="width:200px">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{controller.available.cars}" />
    <f:converter converterId="carConverter" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

And this is my converter:

```
@FacesConverter("carConverter")
public class CarConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String newValue) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return "";
        }
        if (object instanceof Car) {
            Car car = (Car) object;
            String name = car.getName();
            return name;
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(object + " is not a valid car"));
        }
    }
}
```

`getAsString()` returns the correct String. But the `selectCheckboxMenu` still lists the objects and not the Strings.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The converter is not for the label but for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show the car name in checkboxMenu label you have to use the  selectItems' itemLabel attribute

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg.cars}: " for="cars" />
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="cars"
    value="#{controller.selected.cars}"
    converter="carConverter"
    filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
    panelStyle="width:200px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.available.cars}" var="car" itemLabel="#{car.name}" itemValue="#{car}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

BTW don't declare two converters (one via converter attribute and the other via f:converter), and override correctly the getAsObject method (it's needed during the Apply Request Values phase). Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html) for the details